# How to get an icon associated with a certain file type using PyQt/PySide?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyside, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

I have a  `QListView` that adds a newly added file to a folder using `QFileSystemWatcher`, however I also want `QListView` to show the icon for that filetype just as `QFileSystemModel` would add. I do not want to add any custom icon only the icon that Operating system has registered for the specific to file type.

Comment: Use `QFileIconProvider::icon(const QFileInfo & info)`.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to achieve this using the code below:

```
    fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(path)
    iconProvider = QtGui.QFileIconProvider()
    icon = iconProvider.icon(fileInfo)
```